# MVC4 not displaying DefaultValues

Tags: view, asp.net-mvc-4, default-value

In my model:

```
[Required]
    [DefaultValue("Some text ...")]
    public string SomeValue{ get; set; }
```

In my view:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SomeValue)
```

At start the textbox is empty, I'd like it to contain the default value.

Thank you if you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the value in the constructor of your model...

```
public class MyModel {

    public MyModel() {
        SomeValue = "Some text...";
    }

    [Required]
    [DefaultValue("Some text ...")]
    public string SomeValue{ get; set; }
}
```

The `DefaultValueAttribute` isn't for setting the value - it is for comparing it later. For example, when the model is mapped from the user input, you can check if `SomeValue` has been entered or not because you can check whether it is the same as `DefaultValue`.

Comment: Of course I can do this but ... what is the purpose of [DefaultValue("Some text ...")] then ?

Comment: As far as I was aware `DefaultValue` allows you to compare the current value to see if it is the default - I have updated the answer to explain in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311339

> [...] However, the DefaultValue attribute does not cause the initial value to be initialized with the attribute's value.